# Choose item by name and color

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, google-chrome-extension, bots

I want my bot to choose an item from this site https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/t-shirts, by name and color, but I was able to make it work only when it's choosing by name or color, not both. The code of it looks like this

```
function pickItem() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("itemName", function(data) {
        let items = document.getElementsByClassName("name-link");

        for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if ((items[i].innerHTML).includes(data.itemName)) {
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: items[i].href});
                break;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This code is supposed to choose both name and color, but isn't working. I would be very thankful for any hints.

```
function pickItem() {
    let items = document.getElementsByClassName("name-link");

    chrome.storage.sync.get(["itemName", "color"], function(data) {

        for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if ((items[i].innerHTML).includes(data.itemName)) {
                var name_item_found = items[i];

                for(j= 0; j < name_item_found.length; j++) {
                    if((name_item_found[j].innerHTML).includes(data.color)) {
                        
                        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: name_item_found[j].href});
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with the nested for-loop, but the color attribute is not found in the innerHTML but rather in <element>.style.color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, so I'm posting it here if someone has the same problem in the future.

```
function pickItem() {
    let items = document.getElementsByClassName("name-link");

    chrome.storage.sync.get(["itemName", "color"], function(data) {
        for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if(items[i].innerHTML == data.itemName) {
                for(j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                    if(items[j].innerHTML == data.color) {
                            if(items[i].href == items[j].href) {
                                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: items[i, j].href})
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```